# Create executable Jar file under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a Java application and I want to create jar file for this application. This application imported other external jar files by Build Path>Add External Jar File.
How can I generate executable JAR file for this application in Ubuntu with these external libraries dependencies?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: I use eclipse kepler version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To create a new runnable JAR file in the workbench:

1. From the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
2. Expand the Java node and select Runnable JAR file. Click Next.
3. In the Runnable JAR File
   Specification page, select a 'Java Application' launch configuration
   to use to create a runnable JAR.
4. In the Export destination field, either type or click Browse to
   select a location for the JAR file.
5. Select an appropriate library handling strategy.
6. Optionally, you can also create an ANT script to quickly regenerate
   a previously created runnable JAR file.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to create an executable jar file from ubuntu command line(terminal). Because I want to use this executable jar file from other application. When I generate an executable jar file from eclipse there are no libraries files are included.That's why?

Comment: The runnable jar export window in eclipse has a radio button where you can choose to package the required libraries into the jar.

Comment: The `Launch Configuration` setting is blank, so there is nothing I can choose. What do I do?

Comment: Hi, I did as followed and I can't run my jar. how can i run it?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project which one you want to create executable jar

```
-> Export -> Runnable jar
```

[image]

```
-> Select the Main class in "Launch Configuration" -> Export destination (your system path) -> Finish
```

[image]