# Runnable Jar file is not working when Exporting from Eclipse- Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, executable-jar, jaxbelement, runnable-jar

I have a program that when I execute it `eclipse`, it works, but when I export it as a `Executable JAR file` it does  not work 
It gives me this error 
`Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException`
[image]

I am using these classes in my `Main` Method...
Can anyone help me about this?

This is the version of my JAVA
`jre1.8.0_251`

Comment: how are you exporting runnable jar? what is not working?  have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113692/create-executable-jar-file-under-eclipse

Comment: I exported it Via File---> Export--> Runnable Jar File, but I can run it via cmd command but not with double clicking

Comment: did you select launch configuration while exporting runnable jar?

Comment: Yes, I selected my Main.java file

Comment: does it take any cmd line arguments? cmd like this java -jar ExportXML.jar

Comment: Actually when I run it in cmd, it launch, but I need to run it with double clicking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: I modify my question...