# Java: export as a JAR file not working and not saving changes made to resource files

Tags: java, jar, export

In my java class we were given a ZIP file to download which contained a folder to extract that had all of the assignment resources in it and the java script. So I export the folder, open it though eclipse and make the changes. This consisted of putting some photos into the BIN and SRC resource files and changing some text around in the Java file. After the changes are made we are supposed to export the file as a JAR which is where my problem lies.

Every time I try and export to a JAR, the JAR either wont open (if I use the "Export Java source files and resources" option) or will say the JAR file has an error or is corrupted (if I use the "Export generated class files and resources" option). The 2nd option which gives me the corrupt or error file also says that errors occurred while exporting the file as well while the 1st option just exports with no problems. So that is problem 1.

Problem 2 is that for either export option, every time I open the JAR file with WinRAR and look at the files, none of my changes were saved. None of my imported/applied JPG files for exported into the JAR file and sense I cant use the JAR alone I can't tell if it did not save my Java file changes as well.

I don't really know what else to try other than the two export options given. I was hoping it would work this time but considering I had a similar problem with my previous project I guess I am not surprised in the least.

(EDIT)
So exporting it as a runnable JAR file made it so I could open the JAR file but it did not solve the issue of my .JPG files not being saved in the resource folders.
I can confirm that it did save my Java file changes though.

Comment: Without seeing any code, we can only guess at the problem.  Is your program trying to write to its own .jar entries?  That is not supported.  Programs should never modify themselves.  If you want to save the user’s work, save it to a known location like the Documents subdirectory of the user’s home directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create executable Jar file under Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113692/create-executable-jar-file-under-eclipse)